# Suppose you are given an ordered field $F$. You dont know exactly what set $F$ is, but...

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

Suppose you are given an ordered field $F$. You dont know exactly what set $F$ is, but you know there exists a nonempty subset $A\subset F$ with no upper bound. What can we say about $F$? Namely, can we determine if $F$ is a complete ordered field.

Comment: What about $A = \mathbb{N} \subset F = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Doesn't any field satisfy this? $F\subseteq F$ can't have an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field of rational numbers is ordered, it contains unbounded subsets and it is not complete.